# I am constantly getting error while using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

```
from scipy.stats import norm
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-1.8.0.tar.gz (38.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [188 lines of output]
setup.py:482: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/2c/g60zb3hn3f31y6d7v7_ybd2h0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-3xi9itw3'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
Running from SciPy source directory.
Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
Processing scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx
Processing scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx
Processing scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx
Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx
Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
Processing scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.pyx
Processing scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_sqrtm_triu.pyx
Processing scipy/linalg/_cythonized_array_utils.pyx
Processing scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.pyx
Processing scipy/linalg/cython_blas.pyx
Processing scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx.in
Processing scipy/optimize/_group_columns.pyx
Processing scipy/optimize/_bglu_dense.pyx
Processing scipy/optimize/_trlib/_trlib.pyx
Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_constants.pyx
Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_wrapper.pyx
Processing scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.pyx
Processing scipy/optimize/cython_optimize/_zeros.pyx.in
Processing scipy/optimize/tnc/_moduleTNC.pyx
Processing scipy/io/matlab/_streams.pyx
Processing scipy/io/matlab/_mio_utils.pyx
Processing scipy/io/matlab/_mio5_utils.pyx
Processing scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.pyx
Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_def.pyx
Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_call.pyx
Processing scipy/_lib/messagestream.pyx
Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pyx
Processing scipy/special/cython_special.pyx
Processing scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx
Processing scipy/special/_comb.pyx
Processing scipy/special/_test_round.pyx
Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyx
Processing scipy/fftpack/convolve.pyx
Processing scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx
Processing scipy/interpolate/_bspl.pyx
Processing scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.pyx
Processing scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx.in
Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.pyx
Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.pyx
Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_flow.pyx
Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.pyx
Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_matching.pyx
Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.pyx
Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.pyx
Processing scipy/spatial/_qhull.pyx
Processing scipy/spatial/_ckdtree.pyx
Processing scipy/spatial/_voronoi.pyx
Processing scipy/spatial/_hausdorff.pyx
Processing scipy/spatial/transform/_rotation.pyx
Processing scipy/signal/_max_len_seq_inner.pyx
Processing scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx
Processing scipy/signal/_upfirdn_apply.pyx
Processing scipy/signal/_spectral.pyx
Processing scipy/signal/_sosfilt.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_stats.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_qmc_cy.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_biasedurn.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_sobol.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/nbinom_ufunc.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/hypergeom_ufunc.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/binom_ufunc.pyx
Processing scipy/stats/_unuran/unuran_wrapper.pyx
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:470:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:515:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1476:21: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1476:28: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
warning: unuran_wrapper.pyx:1476:36: Non-trivial type declarators in shared declaration (e.g. mix of pointers and values). Each pointer declaration should be on its own line.
Cythonizing sources
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
customize UnixCCompiler
libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
NOT AVAILABLE

```
  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  flame_info:
    libraries flame not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  /private/var/folders/2c/g60zb3hn3f31y6d7v7_ybd2h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dgf58vkd/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  /private/var/folders/2c/g60zb3hn3f31y6d7v7_ybd2h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dgf58vkd/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/2c/g60zb3hn3f31y6d7v7_ybd2h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dgf58vkd/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "/private/var/folders/2c/g60zb3hn3f31y6d7v7_ybd2h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dgf58vkd/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/private/var/folders/2c/g60zb3hn3f31y6d7v7_ybd2h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dgf58vkd/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 626, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 622, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/private/var/folders/2c/g60zb3hn3f31y6d7v7_ybd2h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dgf58vkd/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 522, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError(msg)
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
  To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
  See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?